# AEM Package Manager not Installing Package filters properly in target production environment

Tags: aem, package-managers

I am new to AEM, I am trying to install a package in production environment.

1. I downloaded an existing package from QA Author with one filter no rules:    `/etc/tags/name-us-2/video`.
2. I checked the zip files it contains 9 sub folders no files on any of the subfolders.
3. I looked at QA CRXDE Lite it has 9 sub folders as well and no files on any of the subfolders.
4. My Production has an existing branch called `/etc/tags/name-us-2/` with 3 subfolders non subfolders are called `video`.
5. In my Production Author I Upload Package, I browse for that zip folder package that I download on List #1, Build and Installed.
6. Checked Production Author CEXDE Lite for `/etc/tags/name-us-2/video`, does not exists.
7. Troubleshooting reinstalled it again - checked does not exist.
8. I Uninstalled the package and deleted the package. And I follow the steps 1 - 5 again, and again does not exists.

I hope someone knows the answer why is not installing properly. I have installed other packages before and they all work but not this one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I find your description somewhat difficult to follow. Can you describe, step by step what you do to the package on each instance? Preferably as a list of steps.

Comment: @yescobar1 Generally when you create a package with filters (with out any exclude/include rules on filters) if the content is present in the source system then the package should pick it up after build, and it should be present/created in target system after installation. **you can  verify the filters in downloaded package by unzipping it, and see if the desired folders and the nodes related files are exist for the packaged filters.** will it be possible to share your package filters and rules, so that we can check what's went wrong with your filters.?

Comment: @toniedzwiedz I added the lists in steps.

Comment: @Var I edit my question and I added the 1 filter I have and no rules.

Comment: are there any errors in the package manager console when uploading/installing the package to the production instance?

Comment: @yescobar1 After uploading into production, are you doing **build & install**  or only **install**  ?

Comment: @mickleroy - theres no errors everything looked like if it was successful installed but when I check is not installed.

Comment: I suspect you're only creating the package definition but not actually building the package on the QA instance. Make sure you click "Build".

Comment: @VAr I did a build & install in that order.

Comment: I also try adding another filter `/etc/tags/name-us-2/video/falcon` from one of the subfolders name to see if that would get installed. It did not work either.

Comment: @mickleroy - so I need to a build the package in the QA instance before I download to my local machine? But when I open the zip folder that I had downloaded I see all the sub folders under `/video` subfolders

Comment: you need to do **build** on QA environment, and only **install** operation on the target system, if you do a build and install again in the target (i.e.production) environment, you are pulling the filters again in the target system and installing back to the same environment.

Comment: QA: build - > download. Prod: upload -> install. Do not build again after the upload to prod.

Comment: oh ok let me try that.

Comment: It worked!!! I did not know that I needed to do a build on QA and no build after I uploaded to Production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not build the package again after uploading it to the production environment.

To make your changes appear in production, simply **build** and **download** the package from QA then **upload** and **install** in production.

Comment: I lost the better part of day before finding this answer. Thank you for ending the suffering.